# What do I have to do to have FDE + a good keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, truecrypt, bitlocker

I am really frustrated.  I have 2 computers, both with relatively expensive keyboards.  Both computers are protected with a full disk encryption (FDE) product.  On both systems I cannot type the password to unlock the encryption using my main USB keyboard attached to those systems.  But I can provide the password using a cheap Dell keyboard.

After the encryption password is provided with the cheap keyboard and the computers are booted the main keyboards work just fine.

Is there some good reason, that I can provide my password for the FDE using my cheap Dell keyboard on both systems, but My DAS4 or G11 doesn't work on either?

This issue applies to both Truecrypt, and Bitlocker.  One system is running Windows 7 Pro, and one is Windows 8.1 Pro.  I have tried 3 keyboards in the two systems, a DAS4, a Logitech G11, and a cheap Dell.  Only the Dell works for providing the FDE passwords.

Since the same symptoms seem to apply to multiple computers with multiple FDE products, it is hard to blame the BIOS or anything specific to a computer.  Is there some feature of some USB keyboards that makes them incompatible with providing any input at the point of booting where bitlocker & truecrypt prompt for a password?

Computer 1

- [Das Keyboard 4 Ultimate](http://www.daskeyboard.com/daskeyboard-4-ultimate/)
- Razer Orbweaver Mechanical PC
- Full Disk Encryption with Bitlocker, [configured to ask for password at startup](http://rc.partners.org/kbase?cat_id=9&art_id=245)
- Custom system

  - Gigabyte GA-Z87X-UD5H
  - I7-4770k
  - Corsair 32GB RAM
  - etc... (nothing out of the ordinary)

Computer 2

- [Logitech G11 Gaming Keyboard](http://support.logitech.com/product/g11-gaming-keyboard)
- Full Disk Encryption with Truecrypt
- Dell Optiplex 990 Desktop

Details about symptoms.

- Both computers have been booted with only the keyboard(s) [DAS4,G11] connected and no other USB devices.
- I have tried connecting the keyboard to each USB port on the back/front.  Just incase some ports were special for some reason.
- The non-functioning keyboards show no sign of any keys functioning at all when I attempt to type.  Compared to '*' that shows up in the password dialog when I use the cheapo Dell keyboard.
- I using US/English version of Windows, the keyboards are a standard US/English layout.  My password doesn't have any particularly special characters, it is just long.

Comment: The most obvious explanation would be that the keyboard layouts differ in some subtle way causing you to type the password incorrectly on one of the keyboards.

Comment: Good point there. Are the PC's configured to a different native language than the OS? Also, have you used any extended characters in your passcode? Try resetting the code to something simpler as a test,

Comment: Bitlocker at least displays a `*` for each character typed into the password inputbox.  Even if the keys were not mapped correctly I would still expect to see it recognising that I was pressing the keys.  Nothing shows when I type on the DAS4 or Logitech.  It is as if not even connected.  The password is ~30 characters that match the regex `[-_a-zA-Z0-9.,$^]`.  Everything is set to US.

Comment: Hang on, what else is plugged in to the USB ports? Have you tried unplugging everything else?

Comment: Yes, I have tried unplugging everything else.  Even with only the keyboard connected I see no indication of any activity when typing.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. Have you tried leaving it for a couple of minutes after booting and before typing? Saw some comments about slow startup time. If not, I'd recommend contacting the manufacturer. DAS seem pretty open.

Comment: I think you are all getting confused with not typing the correct letter and not typing anything at all.

Comment: @JulianKnight I have been intermittently searching for solutions to this problem for months, so don't feel bad about it not being easy. :(  I upgraded to the DAS4 partly because I couldn't use the LogitechG11 to enter the passwords.  I haven't tried waiting a bit, but I don't think that will help.  I tried creating a ticket on the DAS support a couple months ago, but I think I got ignored, lost or something.  I suppose I should try creating another.

Comment: @MichaelFrank probably my fault.  I wasn't as detailed as I could have been when I asked the question.  I have updated the question with the details from the comments.

Comment: This is an issue everyone seems to face at some point. Often it's never solved, just worked around. Occasionally it just fixes itself. I would personally try every and all USB/Keyboard options under the BIOS one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after buying a [Corsair K70 Standard Keyboard](http://amzn.com/B00IYJD5CY) things are working.  The Corsair seems to work flawlessly.  It seems something is incompatible or broken with the DAS4, at least in conjunction with my system.

Comment: Seems to be a general compatibility issue, the keyboards must be somehow communicating in a nonstandard manner.

Comment: Can you get into and alter the firmware settings (BIOS or UEFI, whichever) with the DAS keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible, that your cheap dell keyboard has a PS/2 connection? If so, check your BIOS settings to see if you have legacy usb (or similar) disabled in the bios options.  If disabled, no usb HID drivers will be loaded until the OS boots and loads the OS specific device drivers.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)